# Linq set expersion command where and parameter in exernall method

Tags: c#, linq

I try set expersion parameter comand linq where in out 
for example:

```
    private Expression<Func<SanadItem, bool>> SanadItemWhere()
    {
        return xx => xx.IdCol == 1;
    }

        var queryCalac2 = context.sanad.Select(x => new
        {
            dd = x.Col.AsQueryable()
                .Where(SanadItemWhere())
                .GroupBy(b => b.IdCol)
                .Select(y=>new { bed= y.Sum(c=>c.Bed) })
        });
 ...
```

this code work good but when I want send parameter from old select i get error Linq 1025:

```
    private Expression<Func<SanadItem, bool>> SanadItemWhere(Sarfasl s)
    {
        return xx => xx.IdCol == s.Id;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TarazResult> GetTaraz(IQueryable<Sarfasl>all, TarazAzmayeshiView model)
    {            
        var queryCalac2 = Context.Sarfasl.Select(x => new
        {
            dd = x.Col.AsQueryable()
                .Where(SanadItemWhere(x))
                .GroupBy(b => b.IdCol)
                .Select(y=>new { bed= y.Sum(c=>c.Bed) })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `Context`? Do you use Entity Framework?

Entity Framework will compile your LINQ query into an SQL query. `SanadItemWhere` function can't be translated into a SQL operator. **You need to help it!**

In general, there are two solutions:

1. Bind the `SanadItemWhere` function (*if possible*) to a user defined SQL function (read : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/10/08/edm-and-store-functions-exposed-in-linq.aspx) using the `[EdmFunction]` attribute
2. Build your query dynamicaly by combining the main query (`.Where(...).GroupBy(...).Select(...)`) and the `SanadItemWhere` expression

Here, some hints about the second solution.

First, consider `SanadItemWhere` as an `Expression<Func<SanadItem, Sarfasl, bool>>`.
Combine your expressions using an `ExpressionVisitor` (see: [ExpressionVisitor Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx)).